# How to link to a meta-tag on meta?

Tags: support, tags, meta, hyperlinks

Something like [discussion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) links to the (non-existing) main site tag. Is there a syntax for linking to the meta-tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[meta-tag:discussion]`, which renders to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).